# jQuery.html() breaks onclick handlers in IE11 when <script> tags are included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, onclick

How can I embed html in IE with both onclick handlers and javascript code contained in a `<script>` tag.

If I embed some html with an onclick handler using `$('#id').html(data)`, normally this works and the onclick handler fires as expected.

In IE11, however, if I also include a `<script>` tag in the data being embedded, then the code in the script tag is executed correctly, but the onclick handler no longer fires.

In practice the code I'm embedding is being returned from an ajax call, but here is a simplified example that demonstrates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var data = '<input type="checkbox" onclick="console.log(\'clicked\'); return false;" />' + 
           '<scr'+'ipt>console.log(\'loaded\')</sc'+'ript>';
          $('#container').html(data);
        });
    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the page is loaded, you will see `loaded` written to the console.  But when you click on the checkbox, nothing is logged.

If you remove the `script` tag from the data, then the onclick handler works fine.

This works with the `script` tag in Firefox and in Chrome, and seemed to work in IE9 as I recall.
Is this a bug in IE11, a bug in jQuery?  Any work arounds?

I am using jQuery v1.11.3

Comment: Works fine for me, Win7 Edge. Could be your browser restriction?

Comment: `<script>` elements don't run when parsed with `innerHTML`. My guess is that jQuery's `html()` does nasty things under the hood in order to run the JS, and those might affect the event handler in some way.

Comment: I should just point out that if your goal is to use this script as a "callback" for "loading" the HTML in question, you don't need it; just run that code on the line after `html()`. JS does many things asynchronously, but inserting HTML into a node isn't one of them.

Comment: @Katana314 - This is a very simplified example.  In practice I am updating a large list of items.  The script that is included does some housekeeping by calling a javascript function on the already loaded page.

Comment: @skobaljic - I've lifted all scripting restrictions as far as I can tell.  If it were a browser restriction, I would not expect the script to be executed when the html is loaded.

Comment: @skobaljic - Well turns out it was a browser restriction after all.  I working in Windows Server 2012 and there is a system wide setting that is managed in the Server Manager.  The setting is called "IE Enhanced Securtiy Configuration".  When this is disabled, the problem goes away.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. You can always download and test on [virtual machine](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/).

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem seems to be "IE Enhanced Security Configuration".  From what I can tell this is a setting that is only present in Server versions of MS Windows.

When this setting is on, the above problem persists.  Turning off the setting causes the problem to go away.

You cannot turn this off in the IE Options dialog.  You must use the "Server Manager" application.